# Grouping Radio Button Input elements in loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have this UI:

[image]

the problem is that when I click one radio button, any preselected button will become unselected. So that's telling me that there aren't different input groups - all of the `<input>` tags are probably in one big group.

This is probably a pretty vanilla problem, but I am simply not an HTML or Angular expert.

Here is the code for this, there is an outer loop and an inner loop using ng-repeat:

```
 <form name="myQuestionsForm" ng-submit="submit()">  // outer form
          <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="q in questions | orderBy:[]">
            <h1>{{q.prompt.value}}</h1>

            <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="aform">        // inner form
                <div ng-repeat="c in q.children | orderBy:[]">

                  <div ng-if="c.kind == 'text'">
                    <label>
                      {{c.value}}
                      <textarea name="response" class="form-control" ng-value="c.value" ng-model="q.newResponse.value"></textarea>
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div ng-if="c.kind == 'checkbox'">
                    <label>
                      {{c.value}}
                      <input type="checkbox" name="response" class="form-control" ng-value="c.value"  ng-model="q.newResponse.value">
                    </label>

                  </div>

                  <div ng-if="c.kind == 'radio'">
                    <label>
                      {{c.value}}
                      <input type="radio" name="response" class="form-control" ng-value="c.value"  ng-model="q.newResponse.value">
                    </label>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn--success btn">
              <h5>Submit</h5>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Perhaps the reason this is happening is because I have nested forms? Maybe I need to get rid of the outer form?

Comment: I was about to write an answer to try to explain how to fix this, but as I was formulating an answer, I found that your layout is confusing.  You *appear* to have an array of `questions`, and expect a single answer for each `q`, but it's not clear what `q.children` is;  do you have questions that have more than one type of form field?

Comment: @Claies thanks, the problem was definitely that one form was nested in the other, I don't think you are supposed to do that. As for anything else, IDK, I don't know much about HTML. I do have two loops (ng-repeat) though, one iterating over questions, the other iterating over potential answers to the given question.

Answer (score 1):

Group radio buttons with the `name` attribute.

> ### `<input>` type attribute
>
> The type of control to display. The default type is `text`, if this attribute is not specified. Possible values are:
>
> - `radio`: A radio button. You must use the `value` attribute to define the value submitted by this item. Use the `checked` attribute to indicate whether this item is selected by default. Radio buttons that have the same value for the `name` attribute are in the same "radio button group". Only one radio button in a group can be selected at a time.
>
> [– MDN HTML Element Reference - `<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

See also:

- [AngularJS input[radio] Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)
- [AngularJS ng-value Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)
- [AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)